# Migrate field collection to paragraphs and split into multiple paragraphs

Tags: migrations, paragraphs

I'm migrating a Drupal 7 site with field collections to Drupal 8 paragraphs, but I'm having some issues setting up the migration.
In Drupal 7 I have a *News* content type with a multi-value *field_paragraph* field collection field, which contains a lot of field. Based on the filled-in fields, I would like to create a paragraph or split them into multiple paragraphs during migration.

The field collection contains these fields:

- field_paragraph_title
- field_paragraph_body
- field_paragraph_images
- field_paragraph_quote
- field_paragraph_cta_body
- field_paragraph_cta_image
- field_paragraph_cta_link
- field_paragraph_attachments
- field_paragraph_video
- ...

If field_paragraph_body is not empty, I should migrate to a text paragraph; if field_paragraph_quote is not empty, I should migrate to a quote paragraph; if field_paragraph_images is not empty, I should migrate to a gallery paragraph; and so on.

In the Drupal 7 site, in one field_collection item it's possible almost all fields are filled in. So during the migration I should split them into multiple paragraph items, but they will share the same original item_id. Will this give issues?
I'm confused and it's not clear on how to start with this.

On the Drupal 8 side, I have an *Article* content type with field_paragraphs.
I tried creating separate migrations for each combination, but it didn't work.

What is best practice for migrating these field collections?

This field is used on the News node type:
[image: Field collection field on D7 News node types]

Here are the fields which are currently in the D7 Field collection:
[image: Field collection fields]